# I used a hash function with tuple, but it doesn't work

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-geometric

Actually I am studying Pytorch and Pytorch Geometric.

I made my data

```
x = torch.tensor([[1], [1], [1], [1], [1]], dtype=torch.float)

edge_index = torch.tensor([[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4],
                           [1, 4, 0, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 4, 0, 2, 3]], dtype=torch.long)
```

and do the process of WLConv(from docs)

```
adj_t = edge_index
isinstance(adj_t, SparseTensor)

adj_t = SparseTensor(row=edge_index[1], col=edge_index[0],
                                 sparse_sizes=(x.size(0), x.size(0)))

out=[]

col
_, col, _ = adj_t.coo()
deg = adj_t.storage.rowcount().tolist()

print(zip(x.tolist(), x[col].split(deg)))
for node, neighbors in zip(x.tolist(), x[col].split(deg)):
    idx = hash(tuple([node] + neighbors.sort()[0].tolist()))
```

However, Error happens : unhashable type: 'list'
I think it is enough because I made tuple, but what was wrong?

Comment: Your tuple contains a list, all members of the tuple must be hashable

Comment: You do nothing with the `idx` variable. Then you override it in the next iteration of the `for` loop. Then you do nothing with it again.

Comment: @IainShelvington Actually it is from https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/torch_geometric/nn/conv/wl_conv.html#WLConv.forward

Then why it works if I used the code with my graphs?? Making class of WLConv and forward something like that